# How do I make glsl shader sources show up in visual studio solution explorer using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake to generate the vs solution for my project, and it would be nice if I could see all the shader source files inside the solution explorer

This is how it looks like right now :
[solution explorer no shaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I3jo.png)

I want to add a custom source group to that, showing all .glsl files in my project

I have already tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
file(GLOB SHADER_FILES *.glsl)
source_group("Shaders" FILES ${SHADER_FILES})
```